# New Flutter project Android Studio Demo App counter app or Application template not an option

Tags: flutter, android-studio

So I am following this tutorial, which is quite recent, my Android Studio build is from May 16 so not too far off from this vid's upload date: https://youtu.be/CD1Y2DmL5JM?t=531

Notice how the welcome screen looks right at the time the vid starts on the point I linked. But for me, the welcome screen looks like this, why?:

[image]

Also, when I click "new flutter project" in the top right, this screen shows up which is different for the vid, why?:

[image]

Spent an hour but can't find anything. Now I can create a new flutter project and selected the right location for my flutter and dark SDK, and have both flutter and dart plugins installed. But the option of the standard "Application" template is not a standard option. Looks at the above options, I've tried them all and none are the counter app. In vscode I typed "flutter new project" in global search, and it gave the "Application" template, and running in with the emulator open showed the counter app. But where is the option in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left side pane, you actually have to select Flutter, input your SDK location, then click next from the same panel. Don't click next while Dart is selected otherwise you will get the options you see above:

[image]

After this it will take you to making a new Flutter project, not a Dart project. Then next to "Project Type:", choose "Application".

[image]